# In Node js, client=require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets; is not working for me

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets

Server.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
client=require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
```

Then, I ran below command in command prompt:

```
c:\Users\Admin>node server.js
```

in command prompt it shows nothing I expect "info - socket.io started"

[image]

Comment: This question is incomplete bruh. Do you even have nodejs installed?

Comment: @Mathemats, Yes I installed node js, I am trying chat application using node as shown here: [Node.js Real Time Chat: Inserting Data (Part 4/7)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkXQEwHn2nA), I installed socket using cmd `npm install socket.io` as jfriend says below I believe In later version i wont get the text but I try running the html page using this src `<script src="127.0.0.1:135/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` it gives error _socket.io.js 127.0.0 failed) net::ERR_UNS_

Answer (score 0):

In the 1.0+ versions of socket.io, there is no default message in the console when socket.io is started.  So, seeing nothing in the console is expected.

This was different in older versions of socket.io.

Quoting from [the socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/):

> Before 1.0, the Socket.IO server would default to logging everything
>   out to the console. This turned out to be annoyingly verbose for many
>   users (although extremely useful for others), so now we default to
>   being completely silent by default.

You can set the `DEBUG` environment variable if you want socket.io to enable logging.  Details are described in the above linked doc.

Comment: so now I am moving forward. I try this code 
server.js
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
client=require('socket.io').listen(135).sockets;

index.html
..
    <body>

        <div class="chat">
            <div class="chat-messages"></div>
            <textarea placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:135/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    </body>
in network i got this error
socket.io.js
127.0.0 
failed)
net::ERR_UNS

Comment: And also how to run DEBUG=* 

In command prompt I tried

c:\Users\Admin>DEBUG=* node server.js
but it says

'DEBUG is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Jeyaprakash - In Windows, first do `set DEBUG=*`, then on a new command line, do `node server.js`.  The instructions you saw were probably for Unix.

Comment: @Jeyaprakash - Stack Overflow does not work well if you just keep adding more questions onto your original one.  You ask a specific question, you get an answer.  If you get stuck again, you ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

"info - socket.io started" is not what you should expect. 
go to your browser and type http://localhost:8080/ and if it gives your blank white page but not "404" that means your server.js is working perfectly.

If you need some "Thing" to see in your web browser then try this

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    response.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Get rid of the localhost param from the script tag.